# Pass a struct parameter to a MATLAB mcc-compiled executable on Windows

Tags: matlab

On Windows, I compiled using mcc a MATLAB script which takes a struct as its only parameter and writes its output as a file. When I try to call it on Windows' cmd using

```
func.exe "struct('field','data')"
```

or

```
func.exe struct('field','data')
```

I get

```
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
Error in func (line 3)



MATLAB:nonStrucReference
```

Passing the struct to the uncompiled script through MATLAB works, e.g.

```
matlab /nosplash /nodesktop /r "func(struct('field','data')),exit"
```

Assuming I still wish to pass a struct and not distinct arguments (so that I can specify optional arguments for a run), is there a workaround? (Google didn’t help!)

Thanks!

Comment: Command line arguments are strings, anything else is not possible.

Comment: You need to add an option in your function to accept string inputs and evaluate it to get actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the info from Daniel and Navan, the workaround I implemented (given the argument is called args) is

```
if (ischar(args)); evalc(sprintf('args=%s;',args)); end
```

which works both in a compiled executable and calling it directly from within MATLAB. It assumes that the user has done sanity checking.